# Macro to replace text if value is less than 1 character - Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have found a macro perfect for my use on here, so thank you already stackoverflow community! I'm just struggling to amend the end last part of the below:

```
Sub Forename()

' Macro to delete rows if there are less than 4 in the NAME column

Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LR = Range("NAME" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If Len(Range("NAME" & i).Value) < 4 Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is perfect but instead of deleting the row containing the <1 value, i'd like to replace it with some text. e.g. Customer.

Thanks In advance

Comment: `If Len(Cells(i, lngCol).Value) < 1 Then Cells(i, lngCol).Value = "customer"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the deletion line with something like:

`If Len(Range("NAME" & i).Value) < 4 Then Range("NAME" & i).Value = "Text"`

Answer (score 0):

```
row containing the <1 value
Len(Range("NAME" & i).Value)
```

You mean replace a blank cell with some text? If yes, then you don't need a loop. Below are two VBA ways and one Non-VBA way to achieve what you want without looping.

**WAY 1 (Using `.SpecialCells`)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Name").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "Customer"

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox "No blank cells found"
End Sub
```

**WAY 2 (Using `.Replace`)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Name").Replace What:="", _
    Replacement:="Customer", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

**WAY 3 `(Non VBA)`**

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

1. Select your Range
2. Keep `Find What:` blank
3. Put `Customer` in `Replace With:`
4. Click on `Replace All`